# Javascript file suddenly stopped working with no changes

Tags: javascript, html

So I got help on this code earlier and it was working before perfectly.  However, upon opening VS Code again the code no longer responds with zero errors.

```
    var runned = false;
    var d = new Date();
    if (d.getHours(5) == 5 && !runned) {
    alert("Hello");
    runned = true;
    }
```

The code is simply supposed to get the current hour and return an alert.
I verified that the js file was connected to the HTML file with some other code and it worked.

Comment: `d.getHours() == 5` will only alert at 5 am

Comment: And getHours() doesn't accept arguments either `d.getHours(5)` will return same value as `d.getHours()`. You would need to use `setHours()` to change it

Comment: @dw_ You should post an answer.

Comment: @dw_ Okay that makes sense, do you have any reference help of where I should look for determining am or pm.

Comment: `getHours()` uses 24 hour clock...5 is am, 17 is pm

Comment: @GAVINALFARO For reference you can check here [developer.mozilla.org - Date/getHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var runned = false;
    var d = new Date();
    if (d.getHours() == 5 && !runned) {
    alert("Hello");
    runned = true;
    }
```

1. `getHours()` doesn't take parameters
2. `getHours` uses the 24-hour clock model, i.e 0-23 so 5 is 5 am but 17 is 5pm
3. `d.getHours()` as used above without an argument makes it work in all use case scenarios